# Change Canvas color from another activity

Tags: java, android

Hi I like to change the canvas color from the MainActivity. Tried Several way but for lack of knowledge could not do it. If some know how to do it will be a great help.Here are the snaps of my codes:

Current State: As I select Orange screen turns verticle to horizontal and crash
[image: pics]

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<xscourse.some.GameView
    android:id="@+id/pntr"
    android:tag="Paint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    /
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public Canvas canvas;
Paint paint  = new Paint();
GameView gameView;
private boolean mDrawingEnabled = true;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_orange) {
              gameView.mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFCC80"));

   gameView.draw(canvas);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**GameView.java**

```
public class GameView extends View {
final Paint mBackgroundPaint;
final BoardGeometry mBoardGeometry;
public GameView(Context context, AttributeSet atrs) {
    super(context, atrs);

    mBoardGeometry = new BoardGeometry(50, 100, 260, 310, 70, 70);
    mBackgroundPaint = new Paint();
    mBackgroundPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
 }
 @Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    if ( mDrawingEnabled ) {
        final int width = canvas.getWidth();
        final int height = canvas.getHeight();
        // 1. draw background rectangle that covers the entire
        // canvas
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, width, height, mBackgroundPaint);

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

I need to change the background from onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) . How to do it?

### Crash Stacktrace

```
03-12 16:25:57.131 6763-6763/xscourse.houndsandhare E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: xscourse.houndsandhare, PID: 6763
                                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.graphics.Paint xscourse.houndsandhare.GameView.mBackgroundPaint' on a null object reference
                                                                          at xscourse.houndsandhare.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:51)
                                                                          at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2885)
                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:404)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:185)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:100)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:655)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:811)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:152)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:958)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:948)
                                                                          at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:191)
                                                                          at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1146)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3053)
                                                                          at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3860)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
03-12 16:25:57.132 728-1058/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity 1 xscourse.houndsandhare/.MainActivity
0
```

Comment: post the crash stacktrace.

Comment: There is no reason to link us to another page... I have added the stacktrace to your post. The error is clear, its because the mBackgroundPaint object is null. Figure out why its null and make sure its not null. To do this, figure out the flow of your application and why in this condition it turns out to be null.

Comment: I think I have to do like : GameView gameView = new GameView(?,?) but can not figure that out

Comment: where is your reference to GameView in your Activity?

Comment: If knew where is that to declare then I may not be here. Can you tell me how to create the reference?